# Adding event to calendar through Json ios titanium

Tags: ios, json, calendar, titanium, appcelerator

I am trying to add events to ios calendar through a json file timetable. It adds events to the calendar but i don't want to add the events with duplicate entry. If date already has exisisting event it should not add it. what changes can be made in this this code?

```
var fileName = 'timetable.json';
var file = Titanium.Filesystem.getFile(Titanium.Filesystem.resourcesDirectory, fileName);

 if (file.exists()) {
var data =  file.read();
var timetab = JSON.parse(data); 
Ti.API.info("json file" + timetab.timetable[0].events);
 }

for(var i=0; i<timetab.timetable.length;i++)
 {
 var endDate = new Date(timetab.timetable[i].date);

endDate.setHours(endDate.getHours()+3);


// Add event to our calendar.

Ti.Calendar.addEvent({
title: timetab.timetable[i].events,

startDate: new Date(timetab.timetable[i].date),
endDate: endDate,
location: "At home",
 note: "A note",
alarm: {
    offset: -900
 },

 identifier: Ti.Calendar.identifier,
type:"private",
attendees: "xyz",
organizer: "abc"
 });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first get All events of the date on which you are going to add Events, you can use [getEventsInDate](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Calendar.Calendar-method-getEventsInDate) Method for this, just check if the events are already present in the calendar, if not add them.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is the right solution but i am adding event and the date for that event through json so how should i pass that value in the function?

Comment: Parse JSON and fetch the event date from it, compare it with the calendar events.Then create another JSON without events in the calendar and Pass this JSON to the function.